# Library for jQuery Parallax Videos

Tags: jquery, parallax

I'm trying to build a website that uses the jquery parallax plugin, but instead of using basic images / stock photography on each slide I want to use video footage.  Since I want to use video footage instead of static images is there a specific library / plugin that I can use that is best suited to this type of requirement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this plugin, a parallax video plugin: https://github.com/linnett/backgroundVideo